# SQL extract for MS Dynamics AX not joining data correctly

Tags: sql, database, axapta

Picking up where a colleague left off, we are trying to pull security role data from MS Dynamics AX into excel files, each individual "model" or table comes out correctly but the excel file that has them all joined is far too big, over 1 GB when the combined total of the individual files is about 5~MB. Would greatly appreciate any help in regards as to the bloat being caused by joining the tables.

```
--Using Temp tables get distinct Roles and Subroles

SELECT DISTINCT SECURITYROLE
INTO #ROLES
FROM [MicrosoftDynamicsAX_model].[dbo].SECURITYROLEEXPLODEDGRAPH


SELECT DISTINCT SECURITYROLE, SECURITYSUBROLE
INTO #SUBROLES 
FROM [MicrosoftDynamicsAX_model].[dbo].SECURITYROLEEXPLODEDGRAPH
WHERE SECURITYROLE <> SECURITYSUBROLE

--Get Security Tasks and Subtasks assigned to the roles identified above

SELECT      A.SECURITYROLE,
            '' AS SECURITYSUBROLE, 
            secRoleTask.SECURITYTASK,
            secTask.AOTNAME AS 'TaskIdentifier',
            secTask.NAME AS 'TaskSysName',
            secTask2.AOTNAME AS 'SubTaskIdentifier',
            secTaskExplode.SECURITYSUBTASK, 
            secTask2.NAME AS 'SubTaskSysName',
            secTask2.Type AS 'TaskType'
INTO        #ROLES_SUBROLES_TASKS
FROM        #ROLES A
LEFT JOIN   [MicrosoftDynamicsAX_model].[dbo].SECURITYROLETASKGRANT secRoleTask
ON          A.SECURITYROLE = secRoleTask.SECURITYROLE
LEFT JOIN   [MicrosoftDynamicsAX_model].[dbo].SECURITYTASK secTask
ON          secTask.RECID = secRoleTask.SECURITYTASK
LEFT JOIN   [MicrosoftDynamicsAX_model].[dbo].SECURITYTASKEXPLODEDGRAPH secTaskExplode
ON          secRoleTask.SECURITYTASK = secTaskExplode.SECURITYTASK
LEFT JOIN   [MicrosoftDynamicsAX_model].[dbo].SECURITYTASK secTask2
ON          secTaskExplode.SECURITYSUBTASK = secTask2.RECID
UNION ALL
SELECT      A.SECURITYROLE,
            A.SECURITYSUBROLE, 
            secRoleTask.SECURITYTASK,
            secTask.AOTNAME AS 'TaskIdentifier',
            secTask.NAME AS 'TaskSysName',
            secTask2.AOTNAME AS 'SubTaskIdentifier', 
            secTaskExplode.SECURITYSUBTASK,
            secTask2.NAME AS 'SubTaskSysName',
            secTask2.Type AS 'TaskType'
FROM        #SUBROLES A
LEFT JOIN   [MicrosoftDynamicsAX_model].[dbo].SECURITYROLETASKGRANT secRoleTask
ON          A.SECURITYSUBROLE = secRoleTask.SECURITYROLE
LEFT JOIN   [MicrosoftDynamicsAX_model].[dbo].SECURITYTASK secTask
ON          secTask.RECID = secRoleTask.SECURITYTASK
LEFT JOIN   [MicrosoftDynamicsAX_model].[dbo].SECURITYTASKEXPLODEDGRAPH secTaskExplode
ON          secRoleTask.SECURITYTASK = secTaskExplode.SECURITYTASK
LEFT JOIN   [MicrosoftDynamicsAX_model].[dbo].SECURITYTASK secTask2
ON          secTaskExplode.SECURITYSUBTASK = secTask2.RECID

--Fetch Role IDs and identify privileges and duties from security tasks

SELECT      A.SECURITYROLE,
            B.AOTNAME AS 'RoleIdentifier',
            B.NAME AS 'RoleSysName',
            A.SECURITYSUBROLE, 
            ISNULL(C.AOTNAME, '') AS 'SubRoleIdentifier',
            ISNULL(C.NAME, '') AS 'SubRoleSysName',
            A.SECURITYTASK,
            A.TaskIdentifier,
            A.TaskSysName,
            A.SECURITYSUBTASK,
            A.SubTaskIdentifier,
            A.SubTaskSysName,
            A.TaskType,
            CASE
              WHEN A.TaskType = 0 THEN 'Privilege'
              WHEN A.TaskType = 1 THEN 'Duty'
              ELSE 'Other'
            END AS 'OBJECTTYPE'
INTO        #SYS_NAMES
FROM        #ROLES_SUBROLES_TASKS A
LEFT JOIN   [MicrosoftDynamicsAX_model].[dbo].SECURITYROLE B
ON          A.SECURITYROLE = B.RECID
LEFT JOIN   [MicrosoftDynamicsAX_model].[dbo].SECURITYROLE C
ON          A.SECURITYSUBROLE = C.RECID

--Get Application names for Roles, Subroles, Duties and Privileges from Label Table

SELECT      A.*,
            B.TEXT AS 'RoleName',
            ISNULL(C.TEXT,'') AS 'SubRoleName',
            D.TEXT AS 'TaskName',
            E.TEXT AS 'SubTaskName'
INTO        #SECURITYOBJECTS
FROM        #SYS_NAMES A
LEFT JOIN   [MicrosoftDynamicsAX_model].[dbo].SysModelElementLabel B
ON          A.RoleSysName = B.LABELID
AND         UPPER(B.LANGUAGE) = 'EN_US'
LEFT JOIN   [MicrosoftDynamicsAX_model].[dbo].SysModelElementLabel C
ON          A.SubRoleSysName = C.LABELID
AND         UPPER(C.LANGUAGE) = 'EN_US'
LEFT JOIN   [MicrosoftDynamicsAX_model].[dbo].SysModelElementLabel D
ON          A.TaskSysName = D.LABELID
AND         UPPER(D.LANGUAGE) = 'EN_US'
LEFT JOIN   [MicrosoftDynamicsAX_model].[dbo].SysModelElementLabel E
ON          A.SubTaskSysName = E.LABELID
AND         UPPER(E.LANGUAGE) = 'EN_US'

--Separate Security Tasks into separate Duty and Privilege Fields

SELECT      RoleName, RoleIdentifier, SECURITYROLE,
            SubRoleName, SubRoleIdentifier, 
            TaskName, TaskIdentifier, SECURITYTASK,
            SubTaskName, SubTaskIdentifier, SECURITYSUBTASK,
            OBJECTTYPE,
            CASE 
            WHEN OBJECTTYPE IS NULL THEN 'N/A'
            WHEN OBJECTTYPE = 'Duty' THEN 'Duty'
            WHEN SECURITYTASK = SECURITYSUBTASK AND OBJECTTYPE = 'Privilege' 
            THEN 'Privilege assigned to the role'
            ELSE 'Privilege assigned to the duty'
            END AS 'Privilege_Assignment' ,
            CASE WHEN OBJECTTYPE = 'Duty' OR SECURITYTASK <> SECURITYSUBTASK THEN TaskName ELSE '' END AS 'DutyName',
            CASE WHEN OBJECTTYPE = 'Duty' OR SECURITYTASK <> SECURITYSUBTASK THEN TaskIdentifier ELSE '' END AS 'DutyIdentifier',
            CASE WHEN OBJECTTYPE = 'Privilege' THEN SubTaskName ELSE '' END AS 'PrivilegeName',
            CASE WHEN OBJECTTYPE = 'Privilege' THEN SubTaskIdentifier ELSE '' END AS 'PrivilegeIdentifier'
INTO        #ROLE_DUTY_PRIVILEGE
FROM        #SECURITYOBJECTS


--Break down privileges to get entry points/permissions
SELECT      DISTINCT PrivilegeName, 
            PrivilegeIdentifier, SECURITYSUBTASK
INTO        #DISTINCT_PRIVILEGES
FROM        #ROLE_DUTY_PRIVILEGE
WHERE       OBJECTTYPE = 'Privilege'

--First part of the union gets permissions associated with privileges
--Second part of the union gets entry points associated with privileges
SELECT      A.PrivilegeName,
            A.PrivilegeIdentifier,
            A.SECURITYSUBTASK,
            B.SECURABLEOBJECT AS 'ENTRYPOINT',
            B.ACCESS_ AS 'PERMISSIONGROUP',
            C.NAME AS 'EntryPointName',
            C.Type as 'AccessType'
INTO        #PRIVILEGE_PERMISSION_POINTS
FROM        #DISTINCT_PRIVILEGES A
INNER JOIN  [MicrosoftDynamicsAX_model].[dbo].SecurityTaskPermissionOverride B   
ON          A.SECURITYSUBTASK = B.SECURITYTASK
INNER JOIN  [MicrosoftDynamicsAX_model].[dbo].SecurableObject C
ON          B.SECURABLEOBJECT = C.RECID
UNION ALL
SELECT      A.PrivilegeName,
            A.PrivilegeIdentifier,
            A.SECURITYSUBTASK,
            B.ENTRYPOINT,
            B.PERMISSIONGROUP,
            C.NAME AS 'EntryPointName',
            C.Type as 'AccessType'
FROM        #DISTINCT_PRIVILEGES A
INNER JOIN  [MicrosoftDynamicsAx_model].[dbo].SecurityTaskEntryPoint B
ON          A.SECURITYSUBTASK = B.SECURITYTASK
INNER JOIN  [MicrosoftDynamicsAX_model].[dbo].SecurableObject C
ON          B.ENTRYPOINT = C.RECID

--Define entry point and access type based on enums
 SELECT     *,
            CASE 
            WHEN AccessType = 1 THEN 'Menu item display'
            WHEN AccessType = 2 THEN 'Menu item output'
            WHEN AccessType = 3 THEN 'Menu item action'
            WHEN AccessType = 55 THEN 'Web menu item url'
            WHEN AccessType = 56 THEN 'Web menu item action'
            WHEN AccessType = 57 THEN 'Web content object display'
            WHEN AccessType = 58 THEN 'Web content object output'
            WHEN AccessType = 75 THEN 'Web content object managed'
            WHEN AccessType = 73 THEN 'Web control'
            WHEN AccessType = 59 THEN 'Weblet item'
            WHEN AccessType = 44 THEN 'Table field'
            WHEN AccessType = 45 THEN 'Class method'
            WHEN AccessType = 76 THEN 'Service operation'
            WHEN AccessType = 11 THEN 'Form control'
            WHEN AccessType = 82 THEN 'Form part'
            WHEN AccessType = 81 THEN 'Info part'
            WHEN AccessType = 85 THEN 'SSRS report'
            WHEN AccessType = 18 THEN 'Report'
            WHEN AccessType = 115 THEN 'Code permission'
            ELSE ''
            END AS 'EntryPointType',
            CASE 
            WHEN PERMISSIONGROUP = 0 THEN 'No access'
            WHEN PERMISSIONGROUP = 1 THEN 'View'
            WHEN PERMISSIONGROUP = 2 THEN 'Edit'
            WHEN PERMISSIONGROUP = 3 THEN 'Create'
            WHEN PERMISSIONGROUP = 4 THEN 'Correction'
            WHEN PERMISSIONGROUP = 5 THEN 'Full control'
            ELSE ''
            END AS 'AccessLevel'
INTO        #PRIVILEGE_ALL
FROM        #PRIVILEGE_PERMISSION_POINTS


--Join back privileges with entry points and permissions to roles -> privileges

SELECT      A.SECURITYROLE,
            A.RoleName,
            A.RoleIdentifier,
            A.SubRoleName,
            A.SubRoleIdentifier,
            A.DutyName,
            A.DutyIdentifier,
            A.PrivilegeName,
            A.PrivilegeIdentifier,
            B.EntryPointName,
            B.EntryPointType,
            B.PERMISSIONGROUP AS 'AccessLevelCode',
            B.AccessLevel
INTO        #ROLE_PRIVILEGE_PERMISSION_MASTER
FROM        #ROLE_DUTY_PRIVILEGE A
LEFT JOIN   #PRIVILEGE_ALL B
ON          A.SECURITYSUBTASK = B.SECURITYSUBTASK
WHERE       A.OBJECTTYPE <> 'Duty';

--Get user information and join to roles-->permissions

SELECT      A.NAME AS 'UserName',
            A.NETWORKALIAS AS 'UserID',
            CASE A.ENABLE
                WHEN '1' THEN 'Enabled'
                WHEN '0' THEN 'Disabled'
            END AS "Enabled",
            C.*
FROM        [MicrosoftDynamicsAX].[dbo].USERINFO A
LEFT JOIN   [MicrosoftDynamicsAX].[dbo].SECURITYUSERROLE B
ON          B.USER_ = A.ID
LEFT JOIN   #ROLE_PRIVILEGE_PERMISSION_MASTER C
ON          B.SECURITYROLE = C.SECURITYROLE
WHERE       A.NAME LIKE '%'
AND         A.ENABLE = 1
```

Comment: It is difficult to help if you do not describe you intended output. Also you have several selects, which one is the one causing the trouble?

Comment: This question is poorly written, but if I had to guess I'd say you're selecting blob/container fields. Just review your joins and make sure you're not scooping those up.